# Correct way to generate random numbers

Tags: matlab, random

On page 3 of "Lecture 8, White Noise and Power Spectral Density" it is mentioned that `rand` and `randn` create Pseudo-random numbers. Please correct me if I am wrong: a sequence of random number is that which for the same seed, two sequences are never really exact.

Whereas, Pseudo-random numbers are deterministic i.e., two sequences are same if generated from the same seed.

How can I create random numbers and not pseudo-random numbers since I was under the impression that Matlab's `rand` and `randn` functions are used to generate identically independent random numbers? But, the slides mention that they create pseudo random numbers. Googling for creating of random numbers return `rand` and `randn()` functions.

The reason for distinguishing  random numbers from pseudo-random numbers is that I need to compare performance of cryptography (A) random with white noise characteristics and (B) pseudo-random signal with white noise characteristic. So, (A) must be different from (B). I shall be grateful for any code and the correct way to generate random numbers and pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: Isn't it the `rand(n)` command for example `randomGenerator=rand(2)`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to generate actual random numbers with software... psuedo-random signal generators in Matlab will have white noise characteristics and most statistical software simulations use psuedo-random numbers. So `rand` and `randn` *are* the correct ways to generate random numbers in Matlab

Comment: Do you need to use "true" RNG vs pseudo RNG, or pseudo RNG vs quasi-random RNG?

Comment: I mean, there is an academic paper there around that shows how to chose a wining strategy at "rock paper scissors" against an human, showing  how not even humans are random number generators!

Comment: Your best bet are [hardware random number generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) - these usually are easy to access from software. Though I really doubt they are what you had in mind. Also consider this [code from XKCD](http://xkcd.com/221/) ;)

Comment: @Kostya: You are absolutely correct to point out that I need tru RNG vs pseudo deterministic.

Comment: @Dan: Thank you for clearing the confusion about rand and randn as psuedo random number generators. In cryptography also I found a rampant use of Pseudo random numbers instead of random number generator. But it is difficult to compare the performance through computer simulation between True RNG and pseudo RNG if I use rand() or randn() for generating True RNG and PRNG !!! I found a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070254/pseudo-random-number-generator.

Comment: @Dan: Can I use this code to generate True RNG? Or is there a straightforward Matlab function for True random number generator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators) that although generates pseudo RNG, but still can be used as a substitute for True RNG. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: @SKM it's pretty clear from the article you posted that you can***NOT*** use *any* code for TRNG. You need some hardware dedicated to the task in order to do so. If you have to do it using software then I think your best best to to feed from a webservice like http://www.random.org/ (as mentioned in an answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, it is really difficult (probably impossible) to create real random numbers with computer software. There are numerous projects on the internet that provide real random numbers that are generated by physical processes (for example the one Kostya mentioned). A Particularly interesting one is [this](https://qrng.physik.hu-berlin.de/) from HU Berlin.

That being said, for experiments like the one you want to perform, Maltab's psedo RNGs are more than fine. Matlab's algorithms include Mersenne Twister which is one of the best known pseudo RNG (I would suggest you google the Mersenne Twister's properties). See Maltab rng documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html).

Since you did not mention which type of system you want to simulate, one simple approach to solve your issue would be to use a good RNG (Mersenne Twister) for process A and a not-so-good for process B.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the algorithm that Matlab uses for Psuedo RNG.

Comment: In this article "Nonlinear System Identification: Comparison between PRBS and Random Gaussian perturbation on Steam Distillation Pilot Plant, 2013 IEEE 3rd International COnference on System Engineering & Technology, 19-20 Aug, 2013, Malaysia" The Authors compare performance between Random Gaussian white signal and Pseudo Random Binary Sequence. Therefore, there may be a way to generate Random Gaussian signal and Pseudo random from rand(), randn(). I am in a dilemma. Can you please suggest a way out to generate these?

Comment: @SKM unfortunately the paper is paywalled, I cannot read it. Take a look at this matlab function [awgn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html?refresh=true). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Generation of "true" random numbers is a tricky exercise, you can check Wikipedia on RNG and the tests of randomness (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation). This link offers RNG based on atmospheric noise (http://www.random.org/).

Comment: +1 for http://www.random.org/ I think feeding off a webservice that offers TRNG is the only alternative to buy hardware dedicate to the task.

Comment: @Kostya: In the link which you have provided, on the right hand side there is a tool that outputs a single random number between a certain range. What should I do to get a time series of random numbers?

Comment: @SKM: Take a look in the Numbers section on the webpage, there are a couple of options listed there